# Decorating a page with pgfornaments

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfornament

I want to decorate pages in my document by using the package `pgfornaments`. To make things easier, I created the command `\pageornament`:

```
\newcommand{\pageornament}[2]{% 
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay] 
\color{#2}
\node[anchor=north west] at (current page.north west){% 
    \pgfornament[width=2cm]{#1}}; 
\node[anchor=north east] at (current page.north east){%
    \pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=v]{#1}}; 
\node[anchor=south west] at (current page.south west){% 
    \pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=h]{#1}}; 
\node[anchor=south east] at (current page.south east){% 
    \pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=c]{#1}}; 
\end{tikzpicture} }
```

When calling it with `\pageornament{61}{Maroon}` (for example) the page gets the four ornaments in the corners. But if I want to add a text to it the text appears below the bottom ornaments, shifting everything away. Why? How can I include the text in the middle of the page (or the top left, as I would have expected it)?

Edit: MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{songs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\definecolor{fondpaille}{cmyk}{0,0,0.1,0}

\newcommand{\pageornament}[2]{% 
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay] 
\color{#2}
\node[anchor=north west] at (current page.north west){% 
    \pgfornament[width=2cm]{#1}}; 
\node[anchor=north east] at (current page.north east){%
    \pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=v]{#1}}; 
\node[anchor=south west] at (current page.south west){% 
    \pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=h]{#1}}; 
\node[anchor=south east] at (current page.south east){% 
    \pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=c]{#1}}; 
\end{tikzpicture} }

\begin{document}
\pageornament{63}{MidnightBlue}
This is a test for a page
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you supply a full MWE, instead of a snippet?

Comment: @Alenanno: I added it, hope it helps

Comment: `\begin{document}\newpage` does not make sense.

Comment: Did you compile twice? The **background** package would probably be useful here.

Comment: @Sigur: That happens when I do not remove all from my working sheet...

Comment: @cfr: Compiling twice solved it, should have thought about that earlier...

Comment: Any time you use `remember picture` etc. you need to compile at least twice for things to end up in the right places. It typically looks a complete mess first time (or things don't show up at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was simply to compile it twice.